# Outputting a variable from within a function within a function

Tags: jquery, file

I am having an issue with a script I have written.

I would like to output the variable `error` with either `true` or `false`.

I am unable to get the `error` variable to output from the '`fileErrors`' function.

Can anyone take a look at the following code and tell me if there is an obvious issue as to why its not outputting?

```
function file() {

    var error;

    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {

        if (!((type == 'jpg') || (type == 'jpeg'))) {

            $('#file-info').html('Wrong file type. JPG and JPEG only.').slideDown('slow');
            $('.upload-button').attr("disabled", true);
            error = true; 

        } else {

            var fileSize = $('.file_field input[type=file]')[0].files[0].size; 
            var maxFileSize = 8388608;

            var maxFileDimension = 1920;

            var fileWidth;
            var fileHeight;
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                var fileField = $('.file_field input[type=file]')[0].files[0];
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.onload = function() {
                        fileWidth = this.width;
                        fileHeight = this.height;
                        fileErrors();   
                    };
                image.src = url.createObjectURL(fileField);

            function fileErrors() {

                if ( fileWidth > maxFileDimension || fileHeight > maxFileDimension ) {

                    $('#file-info').html('File dimensions exceed '+maxFileDimension+'px.').slideDown('slow');
                    $('.upload-button').attr("disabled", true);     
                    error = true;

                } else if ( fileSize > maxFileSize ) {

                    $('#file-info').html('File exceeding maximum file size.').slideDown('slow');
                    $('.upload-button').attr("disabled", true);
                    error = true;

                } else {

                    $('#file-info').slideUp();
                    $('.upload-button').attr("disabled", false);                    
                    error = false;

                }
            };

        }           

    } else {

        if (!((type == 'jpg') || (type == 'jpeg'))) {
            $('#file-info').html('Wrong file type. JPG and JPEG only.').slideDown('slow');
            $('.upload-button').attr("disabled", true);
            error = true;
        } else {
            $('#file-info').slideUp();
            $('.upload-button').attr("disabled", false);
            error = false;
        }   
    }

    console.log(error);

};
```

Comment: so what are you getting from the log?

Answer (score 0):

The `fileErrors` function is not getting called.

---

It will be called when the `onload` event of the image element is fired. But the `onload` event is not getting fired as long you did not added the element on to your **DOM** tree.

*If you want to debug the error variable is correctly being set, you can manually call the `onload` event handler function like this*:

```
 image.onload()
```

Comment: Thank you Degen. Though I am not sure I follow. You say the onload event is not getting fired. How would I ensure it is?

Comment: what is the image used for? if you dont add it to ur DOM why are you creating it?

Comment: I am just looking to check its size.

Comment: you are looking into checking size of randomly created image, why? is this the image you want to upload?

Comment: When the image is changed in the 'file' field, this is run. I am looking to check the width and height before running the errors function to check if the image is too big etc. It works, just doesn't allow me to pass any variables over.